# Sumas acumuladas

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Me podrían ayudar con esta consulta.

Debo hacer un `sum` acumulado, para obtener el saldo diario. Me fijé que el `Over (Order by dato)` no es compatible con la version `Sql Server 2008 R2`.

```
Select Day(f.fechaalta) As fecha
     , Sum(f.montototal) As monto
     , Sum(Sum(f.montototal)) Over() As acumulado
       From facturacion As f
       Where Month(f.fechaalta) = 10 And Year(f.fechaalta) = 2021
       Group By Day(f.fechaalta)
       Order By Day(fechaalta);
```

Comment: Bienvenido/a a [es.so], haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. 1. NO USES MAYÚSCULAS, ya que esto se toma como que estás gritando :) 2. Pon en las etiquetas el motor de base de datos que utilizas (que según el título, es SQL Server). Lee [ask].

Comment: Explicate mejor, seria bueno que nos ilustraras con ejemplos, un ejemplo vale mas q mil palabras